# jQuery: Parse/Manipulate HTML without executing scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm loading some HTML via Ajax with this format:

```
<div id="div1">
  ... some content ...
</div>
<div id="div2">
  ...some content...
</div>
... etc.
```

I need to iterate over each div in the response and handle it separately. Having a separate string for the HTML content of each div mapped to the id would satisfy my requirements. However, the divs may contain script tags, which I need to preserve but not execute (they'll execute later when I stick the HTML into the document, so executing during parsing would be bad). My first thought was to do something like this:

```
// data being the result from $.get
var clean = data.replace(/<script.*?</script>/,function() {
    // insert some unique token, save the tag, put it back while I'm processing
}); 

$('<div/>').html(clean).children().each( /* ... process here ... */);
```

But I worry that some stupid dev is going to come along and put something like this in one of the divs:

```
<script> var foo = '</script>'; // ... </script>
```

Which would screw it all up. Not to mention, the whole thing feels like a hack to begin with. Does anyone know a better way?

EDIT: Here's the solution I've come up with:

```
var divSplitRegex = /(?:^|<\/div>)\s*<div\s+id="prefix-(.+?)">/g,
    idReplacement = preDelimeter+'$1'+postDelimeter;
var r = data.replace(<\/div>\s*$/,'').
    replace(divSplitRegex,idReplacement).split(preDelimeter);
$.each(r,function() {
    var content;
    if(this) {
        callback.apply(null,this.split(postDelimeter));
    }
});
```

Where preDelimiter and postDelimeter are just unique strings like "###I'd have to be an idiot to embed this string in my content unescaped because it would break everything###', and callback is a function expecting the div id and the div content. This only works because I know that the divs will have only an id atribute, and the id will have a special prefix. I suppose someone could put a div in their content with an id having the same prefix and it would screw things up too.

So, I still don't love this solution. Anyone have a better one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, Using  unescaped in any JavaScript script causes this issue in a browser. Developers have to escape it anyway so there is no excuse. So you can "trust" that  would break in any case.

```
<body>
 <div>
   <script>
     alert('<script> tags </script> are not '+
         'valid in regular old HTML without being escaped.');
   </script>
</body>
```

See

http://jsbin.com/itevu

to see it break. :)

Comment: I guess that means my first solution will be safe. I don't love it, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases removing script tags results in invalid html:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This should be
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.writeln("<b");
        </script>>bolded</b>.
    </body>
 </html>
```